# SQL Server 2012 - Update column if condition is met (CASE) else do not update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

In the below example, the columns 'SecondColumn' and 'ThirdColumn' will always update each time the block of code runs. 'FirstColumn' will update to the value stored in the variable `@NumberOfRows` (so long as it is >0).

The problem I have is that when `@NumberOfRows` is 0 or less, 'FirstColumn' will be set to NULL.

Is it possible to tweak this so that if `@NumberOfRows` is 0 or less, then the 'FirstColumn' does not update at all rather than setting the column to NULL?

```
DECLARE 
     @NumberOfRows INT = 0
    ,@NewValue DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@Other INT = 99

BEGIN
    UPDATE x
    SET  x.FirstColumn = (CASE WHEN @NumberOfRows > 0 THEN @NewValue END)
        ,x.SecondColumn = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
        ,x.ThirdColumn = @Other
    FROM TestTable x
    WHERE x.ID = 100
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is update the field with the current value.

```
DECLARE 
     @NumberOfRows INT = 0
    ,@NewValue DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@Other INT = 99

BEGIN
    UPDATE x
    SET  x.FirstColumn = (CASE WHEN @NumberOfRows > 0 THEN @NewValue ELSE x.FirstColumn END)
        ,x.SecondColumn = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
        ,x.ThirdColumn = @Other
    FROM TestTable x
    WHERE x.ID = 100
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform the update of the given column if `@NumberOfRows <= 0`:

```
DECLARE 
     @NumberOfRows INT = 0
    ,@NewValue DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@Other INT = 99

BEGIN

    IF @NumberOfRows > 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE x
            SET  x.FirstColumn = @NewValue
                ,x.SecondColumn = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
                ,x.ThirdColumn = @Other
            FROM TestTable x
            WHERE x.ID = 100
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE x
            SET  x.SecondColumn = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
                ,x.ThirdColumn = @Other
            FROM TestTable x
            WHERE x.ID = 100
        END
END
```

Comment: Whilst this may be practical if the update of one column is optional, it's already a lot of duplication and would get far worse if multiple columns were subject to optional update, in every combination.